# Kinect Centimeters Depth Value With ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, i'm surfing the net for find the easiest way to get depth data, and ROS seem to be helpful for my target.

For my purpose, i need to get a grid of depth values (centimetres), i have to analyze the roughness of the soil.
I hope that my question it's clear.

Condor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168876/kinect-centimeters-depth-value-with-ros/) by [Condor](https://answers.ros.org/users/18386/condor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use  [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) that's publish rgb and ir and depth and point cloud and ...

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0